# How to download backup files which is WordPress Data on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'd like to know how to get files from GCP about Wordpress baxkup.
Background is that it has been expired free trial term of GCP.
So i cannot access Wordpress on GCP...

Comment: If your trial has expired and your server automatically decommissioned for lack of payment, your data was likely removed with it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you lost your data.

Have a looks at the documentation [End of the Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end):

> - The Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first. At that time, the following conditions
>   apply:
> - To continue using Google Cloud, you must upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account.
> - **All resources you created during the trial are stopped**.
> - **Any data you stored in Compute Engine is lost**.
> - Your Cloud Billing account enters a 30-day grace period, during which you can recover resources and data you stored in any Google
>   Cloud services during the trial period.
> - You might receive a message stating that your Cloud Billing account has been canceled, which only indicates that your account has been
>   suspended to prevent charges.

Comment: thank you for all. i got it...